# react-native-firebase schedule background notification

Tags: react-native, notifications, react-native-firebase

It is possible to set schedule notification with react-native-firebase and receive it in background when app was closed? If yes so how or it should be only possible with push notification?

I created schedule notification listener but only get notif when app is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has bugs. So we can only wait for fix or its already fixed.